# How to show the progress or iteration number in console application without changing the line or place?

Tags: console, iteration

I want to show the progress of my update operation in my console application by displaying the number of records processed. I just want to show the number on the same line and position of the console rather than using Console.WriteLine which will change the line for each iteration. Need ideas here.

Thanks, 
Fahad

Comment: I don't want to return to a new line. I want to show the change of numbers or you can say, real time values on the same line and position. It's just lie showing something like when we install windows, when it shows how many files have been copied during installation. Please note I am not talking about the progress bar. I am just talking about a single value to show here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write carriage return symbol (0x0D or '\r') to move cursor to start of the current line.

Please look at sample code written in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class WriteSameLine {
  static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("Progress:");
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      Console.Write("\r\tValue = {0}%",i);
      Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
  }
}
```

You can compile this code with "csc WriteSameLine.cs"

Comment: Hi, 

I don't want to return to a new line. I want to show the change of numbers or you can say, real time values on the same line and position. It's just lie showing something like when we install windows, when it shows how many files have been copied during installation. 
Please note I am not talking about the progress bar. I am just talking about a single value to show here.

Comment: Got it, so I guess the only thing I was missing was the line feed character as I was using the Console.Write method but was getting matrix like effects.

Comment: Thanks for the tip